# How to convert arccos to arctan?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Is this true?
$$\arccos\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}=\arctan\frac{B}{A}$$
If so, how can one show it?

Comment: Maybe try using $1+\tan^2 (x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$

Comment: What do you know about A, B?

Comment: You should add "$+n\pi$" (for some integer n) to one side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the point $(A,B) \ne (0,0)$ corresponding to the angle $\theta$

Then $\tan \theta = \dfrac{B}{A}$ and $\cos \theta = \dfrac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$

We can tentatively conclude that

$\arccos\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}=\arctan\frac{B}{A} = \theta$

but we need to check the ranges first.

The range of $\arccos$ is the interval $\left[0, \pi \right]$.

The range of $\arctan$ is the interval
$\left[-\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right]$.

The intersection of these two ranges is the interval $\left[0, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right]$.

So the formula is only true when $A \gt 0, B \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

No. For $\arccos$ maps to $[0,\pi]$ and $\arctan$ maps to $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$, so any $(A,B)$ leading to negative $\arctan$ or to and $\arccos$ that is $\ge \frac\pi2$, will fail.
Also, multiplying both (non-zero) $A$ and $B$ by $-1$ does not change $\frac BA$, but negates $\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$ thus replaces the left hand side by $\pi$ minus its original value.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=r\sin(\theta)$ and $A=r\cos(\theta)$, which can be any two numbers.

Then if $A\ne0$ the equation turns to

$$\arccos(\cos(\theta))=\arctan(\tan(\theta)).$$

Don't conclude too fast that this is an identity as the trigonometric functions aren't invertible unless you restrict the domain to a monotonic section.